# How to find out why a local redirect is happening?

Tags: macos, redirection, localhost, hosts-file

A while ago I believe I added a local redirect for `.dev` domains to `localhost`. I can no longer visit any `.dev` domains in any browser on my Mac machine. However now I want to remove this redirect, since `.dev` is a real TLD.

But I can't figure out where the redirect logic is coming from.

My `/etc/hosts` file has no mention of it:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1 figmadaemon.com
```

And my `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't either:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I've also tried clearing my DNS cache to no effect, with:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Is there anywhere else it could be coming from?

Comment: What is `192.168.1.1`? And what is its configuration in a scope of being a nameserver?

Comment: Do you have an /etc/resolver/ directory? That's a common way to override regular DNS for an entire TLD (see [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004062902195410)).

Comment: @GordonDavisson that was it! Thank you! If you add it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One common way on macOS to override the regular DNS for one (or a few) top-level domain(s) is to create a file in /etc/resolver/ (e.g. /etc/resolver/dev), and list an alternate server there. See [this Mac OS X Hints item](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004062902195410) and [this answer about using dnsmasq with .dev domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579138/osx-mavericks-dnsmasq-stops-working/19651350#19651350). If that's where the override is, just remove the file (you can leave the directory or remove it if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

What does your /etc/resolv.conf look like? Are you running anything like DNSMasq? I'd also recommend flushing your DNS cache if your /etc/hosts and resolv.conf are fine.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I've just updated the original post. Neither of those seems to work either :/

Comment: Can you run a wireshark or anything to track what the packets are doing?

Comment: neither of the solutions work for me, does anyone know any solution ?